# Aligning div with background image of parent div

Tags: css

I have two div's, one over the other. 
The bottom div has a background image with two columns, one at 40% width and the other 60%

```
    .container.style-2 {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAC7gAAAABAQMAAAB0GXF9AAAABlBMVEX////09PQtDxrOAAAAD0lEQVQY02P4PygBw3AHAG6mlWu52WYpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position: 40% 0; 
    }

    .container.style-2:before {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;

        margin-top: -100px;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAC7gAAAABAQMAAAB0GXF9AAAABlBMVEX////09PQtDxrOAAAAD0lEQVQY02P4PygBw3AHAG6mlWu52WYpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 40% 0; 
    }

    .container.style-2:after {
        height: 150px;
        width: 100%;

        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAC7gAAAABAQMAAAB0GXF9AAAABlBMVEX////09PQtDxrOAAAAD0lEQVQY02P4PygBw3AHAG6mlWu52WYpAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center; 
        background-position: 40% 0; 
    }
```

The top div has a max width at 600px and inside two div columns, one at 40% width and the other 60%

```
    .container .row .col-1, .container .row .col-2 {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    .container .row .col-1 {
        width: 40%;
        background-color: #00ffff;
    }

    .container .row .col-2 {
        width: 60%;
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
```

If the browsers window width is at 600px or less, the background image and div column align perfectly but any wider the two begin to misalign.

Is it possible to align the top and bottom div columns?

Please see this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chriswatts91/pen/yJVXzB)

Thanks for any help

Comment: The fiddle doesn't match the code above, but rather uses :before and :after pseudo elements.  I've answered below based on the fiddle, but it would be good to make them match so others who find the question aren't thrown off.

Comment: @ryantdecker Code updated to include the pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/zBoNWK

CSS `calc` to the rescue - along with a media query.

```
@media (min-width:601px) {
  .style-2:before,
  .style-2:after {
    background-position: calc(50% + 240px);}
}
```

Once the `max-width:600px;` takes over on your `.row`, and your content columns start to be center aligned (as a group), so you need to also have your background relative to the center of the page/wrapper (the `50%` in `calc`) so that they will stay positioned consistently in relation to each other.

However, your columns aren't equal, so you actually want the image to be offset from the center a static amount (not a % of the parent's width, which will change even when the columns aren't changing), which is where calc comes in -- `240px` is the width of your small column, which also happens to be how far from center you need to keep your image for it to line up.